# HTML: How to output to .txt or xml file

Tags: html, xml, output

How I'm trying to create a survey and out the answers to a text or xml file. 
is that possible in HTML?

```
<html>

<head>
<title>Testing the Survey Application</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<font color=black size=+3>Modifying Sentiment</font>
<hr> 
Add positive adjective:
<img Adjective src="http://findicons.com/files/icons/2776/android_icons/96/ic_question_mark.png" alt="question" title="Adjective: is a word naming an attribute of a noun, such as sweet, red, or technical."
width=20 />
<br>
<textarea cols=40 rows=3 name=textBox1></textarea>
<p>
<hr>
<input type=submit value=Submit>
<input type=reset value=Clear>
<br>
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You'll need more than just HTML

Comment: you should use some server side scripting for this eg `PHP`

Comment: what would be the easiest script to use, as I need to have this completed like yesterday. I have no experience with php but have used java,jS,Python,c++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML is a markup language. It is used to describe the elements of a web page.

If you want functionality, such as submitting and processing forms, for example. You will need to add a server-side language, such as `Python`, `PHP`, `Ruby`, among many others.